# Nested for-loop in python with staggered start variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's a simple version of the code I'm trying to achieve:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    for key2, value2 in data.items():
        # other stuff
```

I'm looking for a way to start `key2` off at `key`. So, for example in C++ it would be:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(int j=i; j<n; j++){
       # other stuff
    }
}
```

I need to be able to go through the whole data set. `key` is a string and `value` is a list that isn't in any particular order so I can't just check if `key2` < `key`.

Answer (score 5):

You could do this with `enumerate` :

```
for i, (key, value) in enumerate(data.items()):
    for key2, value2 in list(data.items())[i:]:
        #stuff
```

Comment: Oh this is neat. Does enumerate get you the indexes?

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'll try and implement thisasap

Comment: Yes - `enumerate` is an built-in iterator that returns tuples of (index, value)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over all unordered pairs, a natural solution is using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). This has the added advantage of only requiring one level of indentation for the loop.

```py
import itertools as it

for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in it.combinations(data.items(), 2):
    ...
```

If you want to include pairs where `k1 == k2`, you can use [`combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement):

```py
for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in it.combinations_with_replacement(data.items(), 2):
    ...
```